# Why is there no traverse1 and traverse2 in Data.Bitraversable?

Tags: haskell

`Data.Bifunctor` has `first` and `second` to map over first and second type arguments.

Why doesn't `Data.Bitraversable` have an analogous `traverseFirst` and `traverseSecond`?

Comment: You'd have to ask Ed Kmett. But you can just write `traverseSecond = bitraverse pure` and `traverseFirst = flip bitraverse pure`.

Comment: Is there a useful decomposition of `bitraverse` into `traverseFirst` and `traverseSecond` analogous to `bimap f g = first f . second g`?

Comment: @chepner, good point! I don't think there is, unless maybe you pull some tricks with an unlawful `Applicative` instance.